# Android : multiple task in single button click using if-else

Tags: android, button, if-statement

I have a **ADD TO CART Button** to add the products to cart and in database.I would like to show the same button as **ALREADY IN CART** if the product is already in cart.I tried using if else,but it is not working.It does n't crash VM.But no effect on clicking.

**My Code**

```
add2cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String nm=name.getText().toString();
            String rate=price.getText().toString();
            mydb=Product_Details.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cur=mydb.rawQuery("select * from add2cart where pnme='"+nm+"'",null);
            while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {
            String name=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pnme"));

            if (nm.equals(name))

            {
                add2cart.setText("Already in Cart");
            }
           else {


            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (pnme,prate)VALUES('"+nm+"','"+prprice+"')");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"add to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent in=new Intent(Product_Details.this,add2cart.class);  
            startActivity(in);
            }                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean " not working"? Is it crashes?

Comment: Your codes is looking fine to me. Please describe your problem clearly.

Comment: It does not crash.But no effect on clicking button,as it is inactive.

Comment: Comment the codes and put a toast in that for checking button click.

Comment: when I comment if-else,it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try to rename one of your "name" variables. You could use this.name to specify which one you are referring to but I don't see the need to do that. The problem in fact might be that when you do if(nm.equals(name)) you are referring to the global variable name and not the one you set in the previous line. Hope I could help

Comment: Very glad I could be helpful